# How to fix CSS sheet that has duplicated half of styles over the other half of the sheet?

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

I am currently coding a website using multiple pages of html and a singular style sheet for my first large project. I have been frequently working on all the documents, and last saved the style sheet and the html page I had been working on this morning on a separate computer. I opened it just a few moments ago to find that the style sheet is not how i left it this morning. I had approximately 1300 lines of correctly formatted and indented styles, and the document is at 1180. However this would not be as much of problem, but it seems as though the styles have been duplicated on themselves, with the document now starting not at the start of the old document, and now has at least 2 of most styles, some not in the correct place.

As I am fairly new to large projects, I have saved incremental separate saves for all of the html documents, but have forgotten to do so for the styles sheet. I have tried restarting my computer, and now do not know what to do.

I wanted to see whether this is a problem that others have encountered before, and whether there is some way to fix or prevent it. Otherwise I will be forced to retype it. If anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

Comment: check local history of your editor . it will give you timewise code so access from there

Comment: You could validate your current css-file for example using the [W3C CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_uri+with_options).

Also as a hind-sight I would recommend you start using [git](https://git-scm.com/), or some other form of version control in any and all of your big and small projects.

Comment: Thankyou both. SHUBHAM - I am unable to do that as it was last edited on another computer and the text editor i am using "atom.io" only has that feature as a plug-in.

Comment: Thanks riesa, I will keep that in mind in the future